# IP conflict with IP address somehow in use by Linksys WRVS4400N

Tags: networking, ip, linksys

Windows is notifying me that there is an IP conflict with the address 192.168.1.2 (the IP of my domain controller), with a device with hardware address corresponding to my Linksys WRVS4400N v1.1 wireless-n router.

This device's LAN IP is 192.168.1.1. No problems there.

I can't find any trace of 192.168.1.2 anywhere in its GUI config, except for port forwarding rules. This is just a small-business level wireless router; not a heavy Cisco device with the option to assign multiple interface addresses.

However, that's just what it seems to be doing: when I dump its config and look ctrl+f for the IP in question, I find this line:

```
    lan_ifnames=etho0 wl0
    wl_chip_ip=192.168.1.2
    wlan_mgr_enable=1
    wl0_ssid-linksys-n
```

Of course, my real SSID isn't "linksys-n", but that's what the config file shows.

So without changing the IP of my domain controller, is there a way to change this obscured "wl_chip_ip" address?

Viewing the arp table for the network shows that the router is squatting on both IPs:

```
    Internet Address        Physical Address 
    192.168.1.1             00-1c-10-f6-8d-2c 
    192.168.1.2             00-1c-10-f6-8d-2d
```

But pings are replied to by the server (determined by turning windows firewall on/off).

The only impact of this issue is that Windows keeps logging IP conflicts; nothing else seems to be impacted.

Comment: What port forwarding rules? If the router think it's supposed to forward traffic for 1.2, it will respond to arp broadcasts for that IP with its own mac.

Comment: Hi Paul, these are the kind of port forwarding rules in simple router that allow external traffic to private IP addresses, where the TCP port type is "n". It only works one way, from the outside in- or so I thought.

The router does not appear in the arp list from any PC on the LAN with this phantom IP. However, it does appear in the arp list for wireless clients. 

          Internet Address      Physical Address
          192.168.1.1           00-1c-10-f6-8d-2c
          192.168.1.2           00-1c-10-f6-8d-2d

Is this expected behavior? It appears the router is squatting on this IP.

Comment: Curious how you are "dumping" the config on that thing. Are you possibly dumping information from it's read only boot rom? Those may be the factory settings you are seeing, not the current "running" settings. Disconnect everything and then connect a single device (laptop?) and ping the IP address in question. That will clear some stuff up.

Comment: Regardless of where you saw it in the config, if it's showing up on clients with that mac, it is definitely active. Although, for the DC to be complaining, it must be showing up on LAN clients too not just wireless... Go through the WAN, LAN and WLAN settings and triple check that it isn't configured anywhere with that IP.

Comment: Tim, I'm using the RVS's config backup feature. It saves a copy of the configuration to a file on your PC, so you can copy the config to another device or recover in the event that you botch your firmware update.

When I disconnect everything and connect only my laptop, I only see 2 arp entries, just like the above comment- the router on 2 IPs.

Comment: Paul, you're right- wired clients see the same arp list as wireless. I had only checked the server itself, which has a normal-looking arp table. It's all the other computers on the network getting this weird behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.
The reported MAC ID was +2 (NOT +1) higher than the MAC listed on the device.
There is an option under Setup/LAN in the Config Tool:
"IP Reserved for Internal Usage: 192.168.1.[2]  (Range: 1 .. 254 )"

Comment: Digger, I don't know how I missed this- there's an option under Setup>LAN called "Wireless local IP address" which was set to .2.